# Getting the name & extension of an uploaded file using python (google app engine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, upload, filenames

I am using a form to upload files to the google app engine and store them in the datastore. l would also like to store the original file name and extension for presentation purposes.

Is there a way of retrieving this data from the post sever side or can it only be gathered client side and sent as separate fields (e.g. http://www.tinyurl.com/5jybfq)?

Many thanks.

**For those that follow the solution dased on the answer below:**

```
this_file = self.request.params["file_upload_form_field_name"].filename 

(this_file_name, this_file_extension) = os.path.splitext(this_file) 

self.response.out.write("File name: " + this_file_name + "<br>") 

self.response.out.write("File extension: " + this_file_extension + "<br>")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the snippet from [this email](http://osdir.com/ml/GoogleAppEngine/2009-06/msg00287.html) work?

```
 self.request.params[<form element name with file>].filename
```

Comment: Yes it did! Thankyou.

For those that follow:

this_file = self.request.params["file_upload_form_field_name"].filename

(this_file_name, this_file_extension) = os.path.splitext(this_file)

self.response.out.write("File name: " + this_file_name + "<br>")
self.response.out.write("File extension: " + this_file_extension + "<br>")

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

If your form looks like this:

```
self.response.out.write('''<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"><input type="file" name="file"/><input type="submit" /></form>''')
```

Then in your post handler, try this:

```
class UploadHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):     
    def post(self):
        obj = MyModel()
        obj.filename = self.request.get("file")
        obj.blob = self.request.get("contents")
        obj.put()
        self.redirect('/')
```

The filename is stored in the "file" parameter.  The actual file contents are in the "contents" parameter.