# Getting name of file upload - Google App Engine Python

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

I am trying to get my handler to check the extension of a file upload to ensure that the user isn't uploading malware or irrelevant files.  I just can't seem to find a way to get the filename server-side. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184110/getting-the-name-extension-of-an-uploaded-file-using-python-google-app-engine) question and another said to just get `self.request.get("file_input_name_attr").filename` but in the recent versions of GAE the file object is a string and therefore cannot be asked for `filename`.

Here's the relevant parts of my form:

```
<form action="/path" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploadFile" />
</form>
```

Some posts (dating up to 2 years ago) say to do

```
self.request.POST["uploadFile"].filename
```

but for me `self.request.POST["uploadFile"]` returns a null value

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the [Blobstore Python API Overview](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/), to see how files are uploaded with Appengine.

Comment: I would rather not use the Blobstore as I don't want to save the file data.  I'm merely attaching the uploaded file to an email, sending it, and forgetting about it.

Comment: You will need to upload it with the Blobstore and then delete it. There's no temporary file system with Appengine.

Comment: Maybe I need to clarify.  The only thing I want out of the file is its extension and its contents.  I already have the contents, I just want the extension.  I'm not worried about setting up a file system.  Using the Blobstore would be expensive for a simple job.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to pass the filename as a separate POST parameters, or a url parameter.

```
self.request.POST["filename"] usually contains the actual file name.
```

Reference:

http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html#name

Comment: How do I tell my form to pass it?  The site you referenced recommended that browsers include the filename, but what is the normal key?  I tried "filename" but it raised a KeyError.  As mentioned in the question I tried the name of the input but although it didn't raise an error it came out empty.  Sorry for the ignorance...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, the correct way to do it is:

```
self.request.params["uploadFile_or_whatever_the_input_name_is"].filename
```

Just like stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184110/getting-the-name-extension-of-an-uploaded-file-using-python-google-app-engine?lq=1) question.  The first time I tried this something else in my code must have been breaking it so I thought the method was outdated.  I guess that's how it goes sometimes :).

Thanks anyway for y'alls answers!!