# Get uploaded file name with Google App Engine Request class

Tags: python, class, google-app-engine, request, html-email

I have an HTML form that allows file uploads.  I need to send the uploaded file via email.  I am following the Google appengine Request class [example](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass).

```
    from google.appengine.ext import webapp
    from google.appengine.api import mail

    class MyRequestHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
       def get(self):
          self.response.out.write('''
          <html>
            <body>
              <form method="post">
                <p>File: <input type="file" name="upload" /></p>
                <p><input type="submit" /></p>
              </form>
            </body>
          </html>
          ''')

       def post(self):
          uploaded_file = self.request.get("upload")
          uploaded_name = "file.doc"
          message = mail.EmailMessage(sender="Me <me@mydomain.com>",
                        subject="Email from me")
          message.to = "Me <me@mydomain.com>"
          message.body = "See attached file."
          message.attachments = [(uploaded_name, uploaded_file)]
          message.send()
```

The above code works.  I need to replace the hardcoded file name (file.doc) in the message.attachments tuple with the actual name of the file uploaded.  I have two questions:

1. How do I get the uploaded file name from the webapp Request class?
2. Where can I find the documentation that describes how to do this?  I have done a bunch of searching and can not find reference material or examples.

UPDATE:
Looks like the solution is:

```
 if uploaded_file != "":
    uploaded_name = self.request.params["upload"].filename
```

...as posted 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981446/getting-name-of-file-upload-google-app-engine-python?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of going `self.request.get("upload")`, try examining the `self.request.POST["upload"]` dict.

Specifically, `self.request.POST['upload']` will return a `cgi.FieldStorage` instance. The attribute you are looking for is `filename`. Also of interest would be `mimetype` - and of course `data`.

For a complete how-to on handling uploads, take a look at [this ancient post](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Handling-file-uploads-in-App-Engine) over at Nick Johnson's blog.

For an under-the-hood look at how webapp2 request data works, consult [this portion](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html#guide-request) of webapp2 docs.